# help w/ MS access database to <table>.... with a twist

Tags: html, sql, ms-access, asp-classic, ado

I am trying to more easily manage my table with an access database rather than manually entering data into a `<table>`.

I have laid out the basic idea but I don't know exactly how to perfect it.  Also what do I do if one of my table rows (specifically the last one) doesn't have exactly 3 cells?

This is what I have laid out so far:

```
<table class="tablecenter" cellspacing="30">
<tbody>
<% 
    sql()
SQL = Select * From Database
DR = DataReader  (SQL)
While Not DR.EOF
    x = 1
    If  x < 4 Then %>
        <td><img src="avatar-blank.jpg" alt="headshot"/><br /><p>dr("Name") <br />Hometown: VarAddress <br /> Class: VarClass</p></td>
   <%  Else
       x = 0  %>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img src="avatar-blank.jpg" alt="headshot" /><br /><p>VarName<br />Hometown: VarAddress<br />Class: VarClass</p></td>
   <%  End If
    x = x + 1
    DR.moveNext
Wend %>
```

Comment: That isn't very helpful alt text. `alt=""` would probably be better. http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/ is a good read on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on why there are fewer than 3 cells. If it is just missing data, then insert an empty `<td>` element.

Comment: Actually, you'd want a `<td>` element with a non-breaking space inside, I think.

Comment: No, that's a formatting hack for old browsers that don't respect `empty-cells`.

Comment: Good to know! I've just been inserting the non-breaking spaces, because I learned this crap back in the NS 4.x days. I just Googled a bit and came up with CSS for controlling formatting of empty cells: `empty-cells: { hide | show | inherit } ;`